# How to justify the text and placeholder to center in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i want to justify the text and placeholder to center in my text widget but this isnt working.

```
enter_title = Text(text_panel, height=2, width=screen_width, font=("Arial", 20), bd=1, relief=SOLID)
enter_title.pack()
enter_title.tag_config("center", justify="center")
enter_title.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
enter_title.insert("end", "Enter Title")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
enter_title = Text(text_panel, height=2, width=screen_width, font=("Arial", 20), bd=1, relief=SOLID, justify="center")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At the point that you add the tag there are no characters in the text widget so nothing gets tagged since tags are added to characters, not indexes. New text won't inherit the tag since it's not between two characters that have the tag.

You can solve this by adding the tag after entering the text, or by adding the tag at the time you call insert:

```
enter_title.tag_config("center", justify="center")
enter_title.insert("end", "Enter Title", "center")
```